# Teensy 3.1 no overclock option for 168 MHz

Tags: teensy

I'm sorry if this isn't the right area. Teensy uses the arduino ide.

I've seen some people show off the 144 mhz and 168 mhz option in their ide. I read in the Teensyduino 1.19 release notes that the options were added but not enabled. I would like to know how to enable it or if I somehow downloaded an older version.

P.S I get the 96 mhz option.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Did you look in boards.txt yet?

Comment: yes I see this: 
teensy31.menu.speed.168.build.f_cpu=168000000
teensy31.menu.speed.144.build.f_cpu=144000000
teensy31.menu.speed.120.build.f_cpu=120000000
teensy31.menu.speed.96.build.f_cpu=96000000
teensy31.menu.speed.72.build.f_cpu=72000000
teensy31.menu.speed.48.build.f_cpu=48000000
teensy31.menu.speed.24.build.f_cpu=24000000
teensy31.menu.speed.16nousb.build.f_cpu=16000000
teensy31.menu.speed.8nousb.build.f_cpu=8000000
teensy31.menu.speed.4nousb.build.f_cpu=4000000
teensy31.menu.speed.2nousb.build.f_cpu=2000000

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest Teensyduino distribution as of this writing, 1.25, you have to uncomment the higher overclocking options in the `boards.txt` file, located here in my install-
`/hardware/teensy/avr/boards.txt`

The options look like this, just remove the # symbol-

```
#uncomment these if you want to try faster overclocking
#teensy31.menu.speed.168opt=168 MHz optimized (overclock)
#teensy31.menu.speed.144opt=144 MHz optimized (overclock)
#teensy31.menu.speed.120opt=120 MHz optimized (overclock)`
```